# facebook - share link from application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

When my friend post a link to FB through my app and then I'm trying to share the link as regular
in private message I get the error:

"Attachment Unavailable
The attachment source was deleted or the privacy settings on this attachment do not allow you to view it."

What is the problem? why doesn't it show the link itself?

Comment: Not yet but it seems it was solved somehow. I think this was FB bug.